# nRF2401 communication (extended vs normal)

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, nrf24l01+, arduino-pro-micro, wireless

Communicating to the antenna-less version from an extended range nRF2401 seems to produce some strange results...

At a distance, the receiver seems to receive a number of values instead of one. For example, if I send a 1, I will receive a 1, but 30 times.

Has anyone had experience communicating across the two models, or is it just best practice to stick to communicating across same models? (Short range <-> short range, long range <-> long range)?

Answer (score 1):

I've run both version fine together

Your symptom of receiving the same value 30 times would be related to a failed ACK, so the sender thinks it hasn't been received and resends it.

I've had potentially similar problems with the power amplified version running at full power causing interference in nearby circuity, try dialling down the power setting on it.

Comment: I agree. I've used one with an aerial and one without, with no problems.

Comment: When you say try dialing down the power, what do you mean? It's running at 3.3v, which is the prescribed voltage. I'm using the rf24network library for what it's worth. Thanks for the help

Comment: Use [RF24::setPALevel](http://maniacbug.github.io/RF24/classRF24.html#ae14164610ab5af94cf44b2743daa8dc9)

Comment: Yes i meant power amplifier setting

Comment: Setting the power level didn't seem to have an effect on the issue. Can you elaborate on the failed ACK? Maybe that's actually what I'm dealing with. The issue only seems to occur at a distance, but not an unreasonable distance. I have two antennae-less nrf2401's that communicate fine from the same range.

Comment: So you tried setting the PA level on the external antenna based one to lower than default. ACK is short for 'acknowledgement' and is the receiving device sending back a message automatically to confirm it got the message.  Try this fork of rf24, i had better results with it after initially having trouble with the original.

Comment: I don't see a link, did you paste it? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: sorry , here it is: http://maniacalbits.blogspot.com.au/2013/04/new-rf24-driver-release-fork.html

Comment: @jmwagg What library were you using? Also, are you aware that clone modules may lack proper ACK functionality?